# Mapping Windows drive path to a RESTful API for cental file storage

Tags: windows, api, rest, dictionary, drive

Is this possible? Is there a programme that will allow this to happen? I have a program that needs to access a lot of data from a central storage, but the likes of Amazon S3 only allows access via RESTful API which is no good for this program. Only UNC or drive letters are acceptable...

Help!

Bernard

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can map a Windows drive letter to a WebDav store.  There are plenty of online Webdav storage providers.